# Palestinian killing by Israel

Tags: punishment

What would be the theological explanation for Palestinians being killed in large numbers by Israel?

Why specifically Palestine?

Comment: Who claims that they are punished? And who said it is the fault of the Muslim Ummah... This whole question is subjective and I don't think it can be answered in a way that SE policies accept.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, So, 23,000 people massacred don't look like punishment to you?

Comment: It looks like a genocide and any kind of interpretations in this context are speculative this isn't a question that is answerable within the scope of SE.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, Are you trying to deflect the question because you don't have answers?

Comment: As a SE user you should be familiar with the [questions one shouldn't ask](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). All I'm doing is pointing at the fact this question potentially being one. It is similar to asking why the last huge earth quack in Morocco only harmed poor people. Whom can judge Allah's decisions?

Comment: This is religious forum, and the questions should be answered from the point of view of the religion not from the SE guidelines.

Comment: @Amt87 Not a religious *forum*, It's a QNA site. And no, SE rules should necessarily be considered when answering. Islam SE is not a "religious site" but a site about religion. It is a knowledge base.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we as Muslims cannot say this is a punishment for the Palestinians. Generally, we cannot be 100% certain of the destination (Paradise/Hell) of any individual because it is between him and Allah. However, there are multiple signs that indicates if he died upon the truth or not. Moreover, Allah didn't promise us (Muslims) that our lives will be free of hardships, in fact, it is in contrary because Allah said in the Holy Quran:

[image]

ِAnd:

[image]

And:
[image]

Therefore, it is all about testing. Any test in this world could have tough questions to distinguish the top level students.

Allah is more merciful to his creation than the mother to her baby. The people who had martyred are definitely alive and watching what is going on now.

[image]

Also, never think that Allah is not aware of the oppression:

[image]

Abu Mūsa al-Ash‘ari (may Allah be pleased with him) reported that the Prophet (may Allah's peace and blessings be upon him) said: "Verily, Allah gives respite to the oppressor, but when He seizes him, He does not release him." Then he recited: {And thus is the seizure of your Lord when He seizes the cities while they are committing wrong. Indeed, His seizure is painful and severe.} [Sūrat Hūd: 102]

https://islamic-content.com/hadeeth/1082/en

And regarding your question, why Palestine? Allah informed us in the Holy Quran that this will happen in this area, and the disbelievers will have power over the Muslims for a while then the things will turn to us (the true Muslims) again:

[image]

And the message below is general for all human beings:
[image]

Though, it doesn't mean that what is happening is a verdict that the people of Palestine is not believers. Because the war didn't end yet, and the prophet Mohammad Peace Be Upon Him suffered from loss of lives of his beloved ones, hunger, thirst, and pain. The prophet also gruntled his companions when the disbelievers said "We killed many people from you", and the answer he replied was: "Our dead in Paradise, and your dead in Hellfire"

We support our brothers and sisters in Palestine, and we ask Allah that he accept their dead as Martyrs, cure their injuries, gruntle their rage, grant them patience, and strengthen their Iman. May Allah help us to serve them and assist them, and may he forgive our shortcomings.